# ReactJS TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.data.map...')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am new at React and trying to learn it. I am getting data from API and I will use the data. It returns money rates based on 'USD'. I am gonna use that data for convert money but I am getting this error: [Error here](http://www.imgim.com/screenshot2018-03-02at165606.png)

[image: screenshot]

I don't know what the problem is.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {data: 'false'};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    }

    getData = () => {
        fetch("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=88a3d2b24b174bf5bec485533a3bca88")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response;
                } else {
                    let errorMessage =
                        '${response.status(${response.statusText})',
                  error = new Error(errorMessage);
                  throw(error);
                 }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json =>{
                   console.log(json);
                   this.setState({ data: json.data })
                });
     
    }

  render() {



    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">React App</h1>
        </header>

          {
              this.state.data &&
              this.state.data.map( (item, key) =>
                  <div key={key}>
                      {item}
                  </div>
              )}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should try to console log `this.state`

Comment: initialize state with `false` not a string `'false'` or even better to empty array as @ztadic91 suggested. Since initially `this.state.data` is truthy, it tries to render before getting the results from `getData`

Comment: change  this.state = {data: 'false'}; to  this.state = {data: []};

Comment: how does it tries to render before getting the results. i didn't get it. @cubbuk

Comment: On initial render since 'this.state.data' was truthy; second part of the operand && would be executed too. So I guess you assumed that on initial render that part would not be rendered but it renders anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your initial data property in the state to an empty array `[]`.
A stringified 'false' evaluates to true which is why it tries to call the map function, but string doesn't have a map function.

```
 constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {data: []};
    }
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7wz9298qm)

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.state.data` is not an `array`, it's a `string`.

Just use the below code and remove `this.state.data &&` from `render` method.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}
```

Comment: i removed `this.state.data && ` and i used the code. It's giving the same error. But now its in the JSX

Comment: it's not displaying the json but no errors. so it's not working.

Comment: what error does it give when removing the condition?

Comment: same but the error is here( `this.state.data.map( (item, key) =>` ) now.

Comment: Probably data you're receiving is not an array. It should of the format `[{},{},{}]`.