# undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.dataBanner.map...')

Tags: react-native

I have already checked some similar questions with the same problem:
[ReactJS TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.data.map...')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070891/reactjs-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-near-this-state-data-map)

I have followed each of the steps: `dataBanner:[]` and `dataBanner:responseJson`

```
...
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'
...
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataNews:[],
        dataBanner:[]
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch(baseUrl)
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
        console.log(responseJson)
        this.setState({
            dataNews:responseJson,
            dataBanner:responseJson
        })
        //console.log(responseJson)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

But the following code still gives me an error:

```
            <Swiper>
                {this.state.dataBanner.map((itemImg)=>{
                    return (
                        <Image
                            source ={{ uri: itemImg.urlToImage }}
                            style ={{height:"100%", width:"100%"}}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </Swiper>
```

[image]

Comment: What is returned by the api? What does your `console.log(responseJson)` print? Is it an array?

Comment: @SamiElk Yes api http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=a3fbcc11e54044668f58e4f191d9b4a0 print data json

Comment: It is an object, not an array, you can't use map on it. Here for example responseJson.articles is an array.

Comment: @SamiElk How can I do it friend, do I need to create a news slider taking the data from that api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
        this.setState({
            dataNews:responseJson?.articles, // add articals here
            dataBanner:responseJson?.articles // add articals here
        })
```

and also you can validate

```
<Swiper>
    {this.state.dataBanner?.length > 0 && this.state.dataBanner.map((itemImg) => {
        return (
            <Image
                source={{ uri: itemImg.urlToImage }}
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            />
        )
    })}
</Swiper>
```

Comment: it worked friend, thanks